# Added volume in a mix of two miscible fluids with different densities and temperatures

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I'm mixing two miscible fluids of different density and temperature in a tank. I know the densities and temperatures of both liquids. I also know the initial volume of one liquid and the final volume of the mix (both measured by the filled level of the tank), but I do not know the volume of the added liquid.

If temperatures were the same, I would assume that volumes don't change and simply subtract initial volume from total volume to get the added volume. But since the temperatures are different, the liquids will exchange heat and expand (shrink) at different rates. Is it possible to calculate the added volume in this case?

To clarify, I do not know the density and temperature of the final mix, only the level i.e. volume.

Comment: If the liquids form an ideal solution (no volume change on mixing at constant temperature) and you know the heat capacities and the temperature-dependence of the densities of the pure components, then you can do it.  But if it is not an ideal solution, then no.

Comment: @ChetMiller can you give any pointers for the ideal solution case? I do know the heat capacities and temperature-dependence of the densities involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the volume of fluid 1, then you know its mass.  Let M be the mass of the other fluid.  Using the heat capacities and masses, do a heat balance to get the final temperature of the mixture in terms of M.  Assume a value of M and calculate a tentative value for the final temperature.  Get the densities of fluids 1 and 2 at this temperature, and use these to get tentative values of the final volumes of fluids 1 and 2.  Add the volumes to get a tentative value of the final total volume.  If it doesn't match the observed final volume, adjust M accordingly.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot!